# Geometric genus of Cayley's Sextic

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, algebraic-curves

I'd appreciate any help or insight with this one:

Cayley's sextic is the affine curve $C \subset \mathbb{A}^2$ with the equation
$$ f(x,y):=-4(-x^2-y^2+ax)^3-27a^2(x^2+y^2)^2=0$$
where $a$ is a parameter which is allowed to vary.

> What's the geometric genus of the Cayley's Sextic?

It's said that for a curve to have a rational parametrization it *must* be genus 0 (correct me if I'm wrong). Searching on the net I found what it "seems" a rational parametrization of the curve BUT I also found another page that -said- the genus of the curve is 6. So, is it 0 or 6? Maybe none of the two?

So anyway, I decided to try calculate it myself with Maple and figure things out but it's throwing me a negative genus and saying "the curve is reducible". The curve is degree $6$ so the arithmetic genus is $10$, and it has two complex singularities with $\delta$ invariant equal to $6$, thus geometric genus gives $10-6-6=-2$. Now, all the tests I did before were with "irreducible curves" and every book I pick starts with theorems for irreducible curves. So:

> How should I proceed to calculate the geometric genus of a reducible curve?

Is there a way to transform the curve to an "irreducible state"? Something to work on the singularities? I have so many questions and I really don't know what to do from here. Beforehand I'm sorry if some questions seem out of place, from here on the mathematics starts getting heavy on topology and a lot of the concepts are new to me.

Thank you all!

Comment: I am rather confused, the curve given by this equation is irreducible (i.e., via ```IsIrreducible``` in *Magma*. I know very little about maple so I don't know why it is throwing this up. The genus is $0$. One can see this since the map $  (x,y,a) =(  4u^6 - 12u^4,  12u^5 - 4u^3,  u^6 + 3u^4 + 3u^2 + 1)$ is a parametrisation (I'm assuming this a homogeneous sextic not an affine sextic with a parameter $a$?)

Comment: @AndreaGranados Have you tried to calculate the normalization $C'$ of $C$?

Comment: @Mummytheturkey maybe I should try it out with Magma then. Also, it's an affine curve, the $a$ it's just a constant for scale factor. I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "homogeneus sextic".

Answer (score 3):

To expand on my comment, if you're happy with a computational solution then the *Magma* at the end of this answer should suffice.

Probably the most elementary way to get the result is to note that setting
$$ x = 
    (-972at^2 + 2916a)/(t^6 + 27t^4 + 243t^2 + 729),$$
$$y = 
    (-108at^3 + 2916at)/(t^6 + 27t^4 + 243t^2 + 729) $$
gives a parametrisation (in fact you don't even have to check that much, only that this gives a rational map $\mathbb{P}^1 \to C$, i.e., that these rational functions satisfy the equation of your curve - hence by Riemann-Hurwitz $C$ must have genus $0$).

Although I haven't worked it out yet I suspect that one can check easily that the divisor of the differential $dy$ has degree $-2$.

```
K<a> := FunctionField(Rationals());
A2<x,y> := AffineSpace(K, 2);
P2<X,Y,Z> := ProjectiveSpace(K, 2);

f := 4*(x^2+y^2-a*x)^3-27*a^2*(x^2+y^2)^2;
C := Curve(A2, f);
assert IsIrreducible(C) and IsReduced(C);
assert Genus(C) eq 0;
```

Comment: Note: The projectivization $C'$ of the curve is singular, hence $C'$ cannot be isomorphic to the projective line.

Comment: @hm2020 yes, that is clear, geometric genus is a *birational* invariant.

Comment: Note: The "geometric genus" is not defined for an affine curve $C \subseteq \mathbb{A}^2_k$: The vector space of global sections $H^0(C, \Omega^1_{C/k})$ is infinte dimensional over $k$. We must pass to the projectivization $C'$of $C$. And since $C'$ is singular it follows its genus cannot be $0$ - $C'$ is not isomorphic to the projective line.

Comment: @hm2020 This is not a necessary nitpick, it is standard to abuse notation and refer to the genus of an affine curve (with the knowledge that we are really talking about its projective closure). The genus of the singular curve you call $C'$ certainly can be $0$ - consider the cuspidal cubic $C : y^2 z = x^3$, then $dx$ is a meromorphic differential and has a pole of order $3$ at $(0:1:0)$ and a zero of order $1$ at $(0:0:1)$ so that the degree of the canonical divisor is $-2$ and $C$ has genus $0$ by RR (or you can consider the obvious birational map from $\mathbb{P}^1$ as in my answer).

Comment: In this case the user seems to be unaware of the distinction between geometric genus and arithmetic genus and other basic results. It is not such a good idea to abuse notation in such instances. Is the user considering a family of curves parametrized by $a$ or is the given polynomial a degree $6$ homogeneous equation in the variables $x,y,a$? Ths user should clearify this.

Comment: @hm2020 Neither of these concerns are warranted. The user states both arithmetic and geometric genus in their question and they are asking about the genus of an affine curve - it's very safe to assume that they know of this abuse of notation. They clarify in their first response to my question that the curve is affine with parameter $a$.

Comment: when a user is unsure of what is meant by "homogeneous" this is a clear indication the user does not understand it when you are "abusing notation". For this reason you should explain your notation and your constructions.